# How to re-arrange the MENU of "Allure Real Estate Theme for Placester" wordpress theme?

Tags: menus, themes, theme-customizer

I am using "Allure Real Estate Theme for Placester" wordpress theme, I tried the below three methods but no positive result in [realtypointusa.com](http://realtypointusa.com)

1. I tried in Dashborad-> Appearance-> Menus and re-arranging but it didn't worked. I got a blank white screen as output on pages.
2. Rearranged the below code, (As its a html code with embedded PHP, it not being rendered here properly. I tried posting it as an image but new users are not allowed so please click on the below link to look on the snippet or code.)

[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE CODE USED TO RENDER THE MENU BAR](http://s12.postimage.org/l03l1jvgb/menu_re_arrangement_code.jpg)

Finally, this option I am very well aware that the 'page order' in wordpress is used for webmaster convenience and it cannot impact menu ordering on the menubar of website but I still tried it to look out for a change but it didn't worked not re-arrangement happened.

**HOW TO REARRANGE THE MENU IN "Allure Real Estate Theme for Placester" WORDPRESS THEME?**